# Excel-DNA Function not showing description and parameter info

Tags: c#, excel-dna

I created a simple UDF using Excel-DNA as follows:

```
  [ExcelFunction(Description = "Return something")]
    public static string ReturnSomething(string a, string b)
    {
        return a + " - " + b;
    }
```

When I go to Excel, the function works but the description nor does the parameters required are shown. How do I get them to show?

[Image of my UDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRZdQ.png)

[Image of an Excel built-in formula with parameters shown which is expected from my UDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZYYI.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the expected behavior with custom functions in Excel, built with Excel-DNA. The description is only shown in the `Insert Function` dialog.

If you want to have IntelliSense for the arguments, you can use the [Excel-DNA IntelliSense](https://github.com/Excel-DNA/IntelliSense) library - https://github.com/Excel-DNA/IntelliSense

[image: a]

[image: b]

Comment: Hi Caio, I have the Excel-DNA intellisense package installed as well but I do not get the the popups. Any ideas?

Comment: You have to enable it inside your add-in, in the `AutoOpen`. Follow the Usage instructions - https://github.com/Excel-DNA/IntelliSense/wiki/Usage-Instructions